# creating data templates using MVC and asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I am currently evaluating the use of asp.net and MVC for a new project (vs. web part or web form pattern). While I really like the MVC pattern and the ability to abstract the code from the UI. I have a specific requiremt to create a custom control that returns data in a pre-defined format. As an example for this project I need to have data returned in a listbox control where there listboxt items contain an image and then values from the DAL. I want to have control over where the image and values from the DAL appear in the listbox control. Using WPF I have done this using Data templates. Is this possible using ASP.NET and the MVC pattern or is this only possible using a web form/ web part pattern?  Any links examples or refernces would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!

**Update** In doing some more reading it appears that I can control how the data would be rendered in the view using markup: As an example if I have a collection (products) that returns image, name, description, price I can render this in the view by writing:

```
<ul id="products">
    <% foreach (var p in products)
       { %>
    <li>
        <%:p.image%>
        <%:p.name%>
        <br />
        <%:p.description%>
        <%:p.price%>
    </li>
    <%} %>
</ul>
```

My question is this the correct approach or am I headed down the wrong path?

Answer (score 0):

You could use some [jQuery plugin](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown) which would allow you to create nice dropdown lists with images.

Comment: thanks Darin. But I am trying to figure out if you can create a custom data template for a listbox control to present data being retuned from a collection or type. If the collection contains an image as well as 6 other data elements I want to render these in the view in a predefined format. If a listbox is not the best approach then I am open to other suggestions such as a gridview etc. From what I am reading you cannot use RAD controls using the MVC pattern (Telerik, Infragistics, etc) so I am trying to learn what other alternatives are available.

Comment: Actually there is RAD controls for MVC http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx, but when I use MVC, I just don't think in 'controls' anymore, i think in html, jQuery UI plugins (as suggested) can fill some gaps if you don't want to spend too much time building components like a custom drop down list.